# Nancy Route defining optional parameter

Tags: .net, nancy

I want to handle below Get request in Nancy Module .

```
http://localhost:9988/myapp/home/admin
```

where `/admin` is optional parameter value.

For this I have defined route like below.

```
    Get["/myapp/home/{role?}"] = parameters =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Optional....");
            string role = parameters.role;


            Console.WriteLine("region-->" + role);

            return Response.AsRedirect(ADMIN_URL);


            };
```

what is wrong in this . this rout is not able to handle below urls.

`http://localhost:9988/myapp/home/user`

`http://localhost:9988/myapp/home`

On trying above URL's its giving me **404** error.

Comment: At first glance it looks fine.. are you sure the base path etc is correct? Do non-optional routes work?

Comment: No, Non-optional routes are also not working

Comment: Then you have a different problem :-) Either your modules aren't being picked up (are they public?), the assembly isn't loading (are they in a separate assembly?), or you are putting the base path in your route ("/myapp") when you don't need to.

Comment: if i just remove "/{role?}" in route then it is working fine and urls like http://localhost:9988/myapp/home it accepts.

Comment: Umm.. you just said non-optional routes weren't working :-)

Comment: Post a sample where the behavior is reproducible